# How can i copy the repeated node values to another repeated nodes in Orbeon

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I could not find a good approach of copying the repeated node values to another repeated nodes. In common programming language i mean to say copy the contents of one array to another array.

```
            <xforms:instance id="main-instance">
                <contacts>
                    <contact>
                        <contact-id>111</contact-id>
                        <contact-name></contact-name>
                        <contact-location></contact-location>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <contact-id>222</contact-id>
                        <contact-name></contact-name>
                        <contact-location></contact-location>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <contact-id>333</contact-id>
                        <contact-name></contact-name>
                        <contact-location></contact-location>
                    </contact>
                </contacts>

                <alternate-contacts>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id></alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id></alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id></alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                </alternate-contacts>
            </xforms:instance>
```

When a checkbox is checked(event to start the action), i should copy the 1st `contact-id` value into 1st `alt-contact-id` and so on.

```
            <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
                //TO DO here
            </xforms:action>
```

Please provide your ideas

Edit: So when the checkbox is checked, the `<alternate-contacts>` node should look like this

```
                <alternate-contacts>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id>111</alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id>222</alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                    <contact>
                        <alt-contact-id>333</alt-contact-id>
                        <control-id></control-id>
                        <control-rules></control-rules>
                        <tranmission-method></tranmission-method>
                    </contact>
                </alternate-contacts>
```

Comment: Could you, please, edit the question and provide the exact wanted result? I suspect that this would be trivial using XSLT. Would you consider an XSLT solution?

Comment: @Dimitre: Sorry, my inital xml node names were wrong, i corrected the question now. Thanks

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I am not sure if one can use XSLT solution in xforms

Comment: Kaipa M Sarma: Seems it can be used: http://copia.ogbuji.net/files/presentations/xslt-xforms.xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`iterate` attribute](http://goo.gl/B0xcl)<sup>1</sup>, introduced in the upcoming by XForms 2.0, but already supported by Orbeon Forms, which you seem to be using based on the tag on your question. With it, you can write:

```
<xforms:action iterate="/root/contacts/contact">
    <xforms:var name="position" value="position()"/>
    <xforms:var name="id" value="contact-id"/>
    <xforms:setvalue ref="/root/alternate-contacts/contact[$position]/alt-contact-id" value="$id"/>
</xforms:action>
```

Also see a [full example](https://gist.github.com/3147763) using this code.

---

<sup>1</sup> This feature has been supported for long, and you had to use `xxforms:iterate="…"` to denote this was an extension, but since this is soon going to be standard, you can now just use `iterate="…"`.

Comment: Wonderful.. I was almost there, but i didn't made use of variables like you. Full example provided is much appreciated since it will be useful to many newbies. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent, thank you for confirming this worked for you, and I am glad this helped.